# Why is this forEach code snippet invalid in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

Here I have a generic calculation function.

```
private calculateTotal(order: InventoryOrder):number{
  let total = 0.0;
  if(order && order.currentInventory){
    order.currentInventory.forEach(x =>{
      console.log(x.quantity);
      console.log("helloworld");
    }  //error appears here<- "," expected.
  } return total;
}
```

I tested very similar code at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
    const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    
    array1.forEach(element => {
                    console.log(element);
                    console.log("helloworld");
                              });

// expected output: "a"
// expected output: "b"
// expected output: "c"
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis after the closing bracket after "hello world"

Comment: there is no closing parenthesis for forEach

Comment: I just ran the code locally and it worked fine for me ‍♂️

Comment: as an aside, you can try using the `angular` foreach loop `angular.forEach(order.currentInventory, function(value, key) {
   // test it here
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private calculateTotal(order: InventoryOrder):number{
    let total = 0.0;
    if(order && order.currentInventory){
        order.currentInventory.forEach(x =>{
            console.log(x.quantity);
            console.log("helloworld");
        });
    } 
    return total;
}
```

Comment: I went through your code again and there was a missing bracket, I would highly suggest you use an editor such as VS code or phpstorm that will highlight these issues for you straightaway. Thanks.

Comment: Yep! That's correct as outlined by the folks above. I appreciate you taking the time to do that. Marked correct :) - I'll assume you meant parenthesis instead of bracket ;)